# win2008 has memory leak with DWPT tag

Tags: windows-server-2008, memory-leak, poolmon

My win2008 server has memory leak. I installed WDK and use poolmon. I think that is the problem in DWPT tag (see screenshot, first row). I try to find corresponding driver using Mark`s article (http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/03/26/3211216.aspx) but can not find nothing. Google also doesn`t knew about this tag.

Can you help me to find out to which driver this tag belongs?

[image]

Comment: install the old Win7 SDK/WPT (http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4847.install-the-windows-performance-toolkit-wpt/revision/2.aspx) and capture 30s of the pool usage **grow** (otherwise I can't see the cause) and share the generated file (compressed as zip/RAR/7z on dropbox/OneDrive): **xperf -on PROC_THREAD+LOADER+POOL -stackwalk PoolAlloc+PoolFree+PoolAllocSession+PoolFreeSession -BufferSize 2048 -MinBuffers 512 -MaxBuffers 256 -MaxFile 256 -FileMode Circular && timeout -1 && xperf -d pool.etl**

Comment: I'm facing the same issue now, a leak of about 6 GB under DWPT tag. Did you manage to solve this problem?